# How can I create a controller constructor in Laravel that takes in two concrete implementations of the same interface?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection

## Background

Note: this is using Laravel 5.3, Please don't judge.

We are trying to use dependency injection with our laravel controllers and push as much business logic into repos that are injected to controllers upon the controller instantiation.

We already have this functioning example:

```
class AcmeController extends Controller
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(AcmeInterface $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

inside app/Providers/RepositoryServiceProvider.php we do the binding:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\Contracts\AcmeInterface::class, \App\Repositories\OpCity\AcmeRepo::class);
    }
}
```

and then the AcmeRepo naturally implements the AcmeInterface:

```
class AcmeRepo implements AcmeInterface
```

## Question

right now we have a case where some of the data of the *same* model is persisted in a memory type storage (redis) and the rest is persisted in relational db storage (psql). We would like to have two separate repos where each repo is specific to its storage type, ie RedisAcmeRepo and SqlAcmeRepo

How is it possible to do this in the `AcmeController` constructor?

```
public function __construct(AcmeInterface $sqlRepo, AcmeInterface $redisRepo)
{
    $this->sqlRepo = $sqlRepo;
    $this->redisRepo = $redisRepo;
}
```

Comment: I think your approach to design the solution is wrong - what happens if model will be stored in one repo? You will rewrite part of your controller code and it will be injected with one useless instance of repo. You should inject controller with instance of some `ModelMaintainer` class that will handle all persisting-your-model  stuff. Then specific implementations of `ModelMaintainer` will have specific injections of different repositories. Controller should be just using abstraction in `$this->modelMaintainer->store($model)` without any knowledge about how parts of this model are stored.

Comment: @d3jn so we're having 3 layers here:1. controller 2. modelMaintainer 3. repo that handles persisting. I've never heard of the term "modelMaintainer".. what design pattern is that? further, what kind of code would be inside the modelMaintainer? ie would it have business logic as well?

Comment: `ModelMaintainer` is just a name. You can think of it as of `Strategy` pattern - you have a task to persist a model in memory. The details behind it should be implemented in separate class. Then when logic changes you will only change the implementation of this separate class and swap the strategy. In your current version you are changing signature of controller's constructor.

Comment: thanks @d3jn, you comments inspired my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429391/7665700)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the answers above I came up with this solution, that kind of uses the composite pattern as well (I changed the name of the repos from Acme to ShopperLogs):

```
<?php

interface ShopperLogInterface
{

    public function getLogs($from, $to, $shopper);
}

class ShopperLogsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * service 
     *
     * @var \App\Repositories\Contracts\ShopperLogInterface
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $manager;

    public function __construct(ShopperLogInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
}



class ShopperLogManager implements ShopperLogInterface
{
    protected $sqlRepo;
    protected $redisRepo;

    public function __construct(ShopperLogInterface $sqlRepo, ShopperLogInterface $redisRepo)
    {
        $this->sqlRepo = $sqlRepo;
        $this->redisRepo = $redisRepo;
    }

    public function getLogs($from, $to, $shopper)
    {
        $todayRange = //get the today part of from -- to

        /**
         * array of ShopperLogs 
         */
        $todaysLogs;

        if ($todayRange) {
            $this->redisRepo->getLogs($todayRange->start, $todayRange->finish, $shopper); 
        }

        $legacyRange = //get the part of from -- to that excludes today's range

        /**
         * array of ShopperLogs 
         */
        $legacyLogs;

        if ($legacyLogs) {
            $this->sqlRepo->getLogs($todayRange->start, $todayRange->finish, $shopper); 
        }

        return merge($todayRange, $legacyRange);

    }
}


class ShopperLogsSqlRepo implements ShopperLogInterface
{
    /**
     * @var /Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model/ShopperLogs
     */
    protected $model;


    /**
     * @param /Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model/ShopperLogs $model
     */
    public function __construct(ShopperLogs $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getLogs($from, $to, $shopper)
    {
        $this->model->whereLogs //do eloquent sql stuff here
    }
}



class ShopperLogsRedisRepo implements ShopperLogInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Redis\Model\Class 
     */
    protected $model;


    /**
     * @param \Redis\Model\Class $model
     */
    public function __construct(ShopperLogs $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getLogs($from, $to, $shopper)
    {
        $this->model->whereLogs //do redis stuff
    }
}




namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    $this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\Contracts\ShopperLogInterface::class, \App\Managers\ShopperLogManager::class);

    $this->app->bind(ShopperLogsController::class, function ($app) {
        return new ShopperLogsController($app->make(ShopperLogManager::class));
    });
    $this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\Contracts\ShopperLogInterface::class, function() {
        return new \App\Managers\ShopperLogManager(new \App\Repositories\ShopperLogsSqlRepo(new \App\ShopperLog), new \App\Repositories\ShopperLogsRedisRepo(new \App\ShopperLog));
    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you may do this:

```
$this->app->bind(AcmeController::class, function ($app) {
   return new AcmeController($app->make(sqlRepo::class), $app->make(redisRepo::class));
});
```

Or this:

```
$this->app->when(AcmeController::class)
      ->needs('$sqlRepo')
      ->give($app->make(sqlRepo::class));

$this->app->when(AcmeController::class)
      ->needs('$redisRepo')
      ->give($app->make(redisRepo::class));
```

Comment: RepositoryServiceProvider::register()

Comment: How do we know a controller _needs_ a repo? What's the criteria of needing?

Comment: so i was going over the docs and saw [this in laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#contextual-binding).. I see what this `when/needs/give` syntax mean. However the example in the docs uses the class instance ie `->needs(Filesystem::class)`, in your case you are relying on a literal: ie if someone called the class and used the variable `'$sqlRepo'`.. interesting

Comment: ah I see some unofficial documentation about the literal binding [here](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe#binding-parameters-to-primitives)